# Query capturing timestamp 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

How do I get this query to not pick up timestamps with the default DatePercentUpdate = 0000-00-00 00:00:00? I thought I had it by using 0, but it captures the 0000-00-00 00:00:00's.

```
$stmtSummary = $mysqliSummary
    ->prepare("SELECT n.nodeID, n.percentRedYellow, n.count, c.Loopback_ip, c.city 
               FROM CATV.CableData  c 
               INNER JOIN CATV.node n ON n.nodeID = c.Node_ID   
               INNER JOIN CATV.CM cm ON cm.LoopbackIP=c.Loopback_ip
               WHERE c.LocationID IS NOT NULL 
                 AND c.Status_Update_Time <= NOW() 
                 AND c.Status_Update_Time >=(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
                 AND c.Status_Update_Time>0
                 AND n.DatePercentUpdate <= NOW() 
                 AND n.DatePercentUpdate >=(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
                 AND n.DatePercentUpdate>0
                 AND length(c.Node_ID)>0
               Group BY c.city, n.nodeID");
```

Added: I tried searching online to use 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in the query, but didn't find anything with that in a filter.

Comment: `WHERE date_field > "0000-00-00 00:00:00"` ? OR `WHERE date_field != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"`?

Comment: I haven't digged into your query but [there must be something else going on](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=649fb81c4e5f4e54c0b7b35112498fc4).

Comment: Comparing Status_Update_Time with both >= and <= should be sufficient. You're probably looking at the wrong place.

Comment: You're (ab)using partial `GROUP BY` and probably getting values inside n.count, c.Loopback_ip, c.city and getting confused.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs your suggestion worked, except I needed single quotes.  Thanks a lot!!!  I wasn't sure how to format using 0000-00-00 00:00:00, and it wasn't coming up in my internet searches!

Comment: Sure, go ahead and post an answer so I can accept it! Thanks @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs!

Comment: @Michele posted an answer :)

Comment: hey, just following up to see if my answer helped? :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - yes! I commented above Oct 22.  I just needed to change the quotes! Thanks!

Comment: @Michele fully aware, more if my answer was the right solution, Mark as accepted :) if not let me know and I'll remove :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `>` (greater than) comparison operator or the `!=` (doesn't equal) comparison operator like so

```
WHERE `date_field` != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

The example will get all rows where your date doesn't equal that value.

Answer (score 0):

Capture Query where timestamp is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

> To select rows
> `select * from table_name where your_column = 0;`

> To update rows
> `UPDATE table_name SET column_name = new_value where your_column = 0;`

This will fix

> `mysql incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` mysql error