# PyMySql: SELECT MAX(timestamp) results in "Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'"

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, pymysql

I am running a MySQL 5.7 server with two tables:

**Table_A**

```
id   name
.........
1    foo
2    bar
```

**Table_B**

```
  id   parent_id   name    created_at (default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ................................................................
  1    1           x       2019-01-01 10:00:00  
  2    1           y       2019-12-31 22:00:00
```

I have this query to get a Table_B entry count grouped by Table_A name with the timestamp of the most recent Table_B entry:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    COUNT(b.id) AS entry_count_in_b,
    MAX(b.created_at) AS last_entry_in_b
FROM 
    Table_A a
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_B b ON b.parent_id = a.id
GROUP BY 1
```

The MySQL command line client returns the expected output:

```
+------+------------------+---------------------+
| name | entry_count_in_b | last_entry_in_b     |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
| bar  |                0 | NULL                |
| foo  |                2 | 2019-12-31 22:00:00 |
+------+------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.0267 sec)
```

When I run the same query in Python (3.7) using PyMySql (0.9.3) however, the cursor generates the following warning:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'last_entry_in_b' at row 3")
```

It might be a bug in PyMySql since the warning is referencing row 3 in a 2 row result set.

Trying to narrow down the root cause, I thought it might have to do with a bug in the aggregation of NULL values in a timestamp column so I updated the query to only calculate MAX(b.created_at) when COUNT(table_b.id) > 1:

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    COUNT(b.id) AS entry_count_in_b,
    CASE
        WHEN COUNT(b.id) = 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(b.created_at) 
    END AS last_entry_in_b
FROM 
    Table_A a
LEFT JOIN 
    Table_B b ON b.parent_id = a.id
GROUP BY 1
```

This generates the same warning but now referencing a column named 'tmp_field_0'.

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1292, "Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'tmp_field_0' at row 3")
```

I am wondering if anyone has seen / solved this issue before? If not, I will file an issue for PyMySql.

I found other questions discussing this same warning but they cover cases where people try to [insert / update '0000-00-00 00:00:00' values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565128/mysql-incorrect-datetime-value-0000-00-00-000000) or [filtering for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931207/query-capturing-timestamp-0000-00-00-000000).

Comment: You don't need the `CASE` expression. If there are no rows for a name, `MAX(b.created_at)` will be `NULL` automatically. I'm not sure if that will make a difference for PyMySQL, though.

Comment: Correct, that is why it is not in the initial query. I added the `CASE` expression in the second query because it changes the warning and might help identify the root cause.

Comment: Seems like a bug in PyMySQL. It's getting the type of the column, and not dealing with null values properly.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm getting the same error. I print my sql string query out which runs well on the mysql server itself, but gives an error from the pymysql code: 

   insert into media (name, platform, dateadded, type) values ("games", "steam", "2019/04/29:12:28:18", "Game");
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:329: Warning: (1292, "Incorrect date value: '2019/04/29:12:28:18' for column 'dateAdded' at row 1")
  self._do_get_result()